# What is the right resistance for an esc with a specific gauge rating in bldc motors

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, awg

I'm trying to build a motor from scratch. A table says 38 AWG (~0.1 mm diameter) is what I assume to be safe operating lower than 22.8 mA "continuously"

Commercial hobby motors on the other hand states that it is safe to operate way higher than the rated AWG (i.e., 4-10 A with ~0.3 mm diameter wires). And I suspect it is due to two things: the PWM attribute of any electric motors and the eddy currents of ac circuits. Or are there any details I am missing out?

1. I would like a different point of view on how the things above works in BLDC motors.

Before any of these realizations about the wire gauges, I hurriedly brought an ESC (hobbywing skywalker 20 A) with an esp32 as the PWM.

I also tested connecting the esc with 3 electromagnets (50 Ω each; delta configuration). To my surprise, the ESC never beeped. I guess the question involves around the ESC and the PWM.

2. My 2nd concern is how do I choose the right AWG wire (i.e., what operable resistance range does it work) to be safe and can operate with the said ESC? Given that the instrument I have is an oscilloscope with only one channel. I've look for some data sheets of the esc stated above, but it only shows the instructions manual.

PS. I can't opt for creating my own ESC. Nor will I ask the ESC company for the spec sheet. It is a school project, and I initially recon it will take less time with "specified limitations" to base my decisions with.

Comment: "Ampacity" for a particular wire gauge is not a simple rule. Whichever table you looked this up in has had some assumptions made which might not be applicable to your use-case. The ability of the wire to be able to dissipate heat into its surroundings makes a huge difference, and the upper limit on allowable temperature is usually more a function of the wire's insulation that of the current-carrying conductor.